# java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String [FloatingDecimal]

Tags: java, android

I am getting the following error (java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String).

It runs normal when I type the number at the first time, but after I hit backspace on the last number left in the editText the activity closes down and gives the ERROR.

I tried a lot but it did not work.

THE MAINACTIVITY

```
package com.i.usvat;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class VatCal extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView code, zipcode, Stax1, Ctax1, CUtax1, SPtax1, COMtax1, TPtax1;

    EditText STP, CTP, CUTP, SPTP, TTP, ProPrice1 ;

    private double ST;
    private double CT;
    private double UT;
    private double SP;
    private double T;
    private double PP;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vat_cal);

        code = findViewById(R.id.code);
        zipcode = findViewById(R.id.zipcode);
        Stax1 = findViewById(R.id.Stax1);
        Ctax1 = findViewById(R.id.Ctax1);
        CUtax1 = findViewById(R.id.CUtax1);
        SPtax1 = findViewById(R.id.SPtax1);
        COMtax1 = findViewById(R.id.COMtax1);
        TPtax1 = findViewById(R.id.TPtax1);

        ProPrice1 = findViewById(R.id.ProPrice1);
        STP = findViewById(R.id.STP);
        CTP = findViewById(R.id.CTP);
        CUTP = findViewById(R.id.CUTP);
        SPTP = findViewById(R.id.SPTP);
        TTP = findViewById(R.id.TTP);


        code.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("StateCode"));
        zipcode.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ZipCode"));
        Stax1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("Stax"));
        CUtax1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("CountyRate"));
        Ctax1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("CityRate"));
        SPtax1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("SpecialRate"));
        COMtax1.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("COMRATE"));




        try {
            ProPrice1.setText("");
            calcResult();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

            TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    calcResult();
                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                }
            };

            ProPrice1.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        }
    }
    public void calcResult () throws NumberFormatException {

        String PR = ProPrice1.getText().toString();
        double value = Double.parseDouble(PR);
        String St = Stax1.getText().toString();
        double value1 = Double.parseDouble(St);

        ST = value * value1 / 100;
        String stringValue = Double.toString(ST);
        STP.setText(stringValue);
//

        String PR1 = ProPrice1.getText().toString();
        double value2 = Double.parseDouble(PR1);
        String Cut = CUtax1.getText().toString();
        double value3 = Double.parseDouble(Cut);

        UT = value2 * value3 / 100;
        String stringValue1 = Double.toString(UT);
        CTP.setText(stringValue1);
//
        String PR2 = ProPrice1.getText().toString();
        double value4 = Double.parseDouble(PR2);
        String Ct = Ctax1.getText().toString();
        double value5 = Double.parseDouble(Ct);

        CT = value4 * value5 / 100;
        String stringValue2 = Double.toString(CT);
        CUTP.setText(stringValue2);
//
        String PR3 = ProPrice1.getText().toString();
        double value6 = Double.parseDouble(PR3);
        String sp = SPtax1.getText().toString();
        double value7 = Double.parseDouble(sp);

        SP = value6 * value7 / 100;
        String stringValue3 = Double.toString(SP);
        SPTP.setText(stringValue3);
        //

        T = (value * value1 / 100) + (value2 * value3 / 100) + (value4 * value5 / 100) + (value6 * value7 / 100);
        T = Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("#.###").format(T));
        String value11 = Double.toString(T);
        TTP.setText(value11);
        //

        String PRpp = ProPrice1.getText().toString();
        double valuepp = Double.parseDouble(PRpp);

        PP =  valuepp + T;
        String valueMAIN = Double.toString(PP);
        TPtax1.setText(valueMAIN);

    }
}
```

Screen recording:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBZ6J.jpg

Comment: An empty string cannot be converted to a number. What did you expect it to do? Give you 0 (zero) ?

Comment: `double value = Double.parseDouble(PR);` I guess this is the line (your stack dump would be nice). Empty string in PR.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Every time when you get number value from an `EditText` you should use `.trim()` function to remove extra whitespaces like:

```
String PR = ProPrice1.getText().toString().trim();
```

You should also check that the taken string of numbers from an `EditText` is empty or not? before converting it to a number variable like `int`, `double` or `float` as follows:

```
double value = PR.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(PR);
```

If you do these checks then you will not get any `NumberFormatException` anymore for whitespaces.

Comment: Did stop means? did you fetch any error? or what problem exactly are you fetching using my answer?

Comment: When i enter the number in the editText  it does not calculate in answer in the other fields.